# How to properly use claims with IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to understand how this works, so please bear with me.
Here is my config for identity server:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new []
        {
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "invoices.api",

                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("invoices.api.secret".Sha256()),
                },

                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope("invoices.api.scope"),
                },

                UserClaims =
                {
                    "custom_role",
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new []
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "invoices.ui",
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,

                AllowedCorsOrigins = configuration.GetSection("Redirect").Get<RedirectOptions>().AllowedCorsOrigins.ToList(),
                RedirectUris = configuration.GetSection("Redirect").Get<RedirectOptions>().RedirectUris.ToList(),
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = configuration.GetSection("Redirect").Get<RedirectOptions>().PostLogoutRedirectUris.ToList(),

                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("invoices.ui.secret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedScopes =
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    "invoices.api.scope",
                },
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TestUser> GetUsers(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new []
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "alice",
                Password = "123",
                Claims =
                {
                    new Claim("custom_role", "user"),
                },
            },
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "2",
                Username = "bob",
                Password = "123",
                Claims =
                {
                    new Claim("custom_role", "admin"),
                },
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new []
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        };
    }
```

And this is how my MVC client is setup:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie(opts =>
    {
        //opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", opts =>
    {
        opts.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        opts.DisableTelemetry = true;

        opts.Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer");
        opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

        opts.ClientId = "invoices.ui";
        opts.ClientSecret = "invoices.ui.secret";
        opts.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        opts.SaveTokens = true;
        opts.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

        opts.Scope.Clear();
        opts.Scope.Add("openid");
        opts.Scope.Add("invoices.api.scope");
    });
```

After a user is authenticated, i'm trying to see it's claims in view like this:

```
    @foreach (var claim in User.Claims)
    {
        <dt>@claim.Type</dt>
        <dd>@claim.Value</dd>
    }
```

But the list doesn't contain any "custom_role" claim.
The identity server logs shows that the user info has been requested by the client from user info endpoint, but my "custom_role" wasn't transfered there, however it shows in logs of identity server, that user has it.

How to access my custom claims in my MVC app?
I need to get them from user endpoint and use for authorization.

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1449#issuecomment-332359065).

Comment: Thanks. That is something i will certainly also use, but it doesn't solve the main problem. Claims are not transfered to the client from use info endpoint. The logs shows that no claims were issued. Perhaps i need to somehow specifically request them from client using some sort of a scope or something like that?

Comment: I see. In that case, you might need a custom [Profile Service](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/profileservice.html?highlight=ProfileService).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that adding an identity resource with specified claims solves the problem even with built-in ProfileService implementation:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        return new []
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResource
            {
                Name = "roles.scope",
                UserClaims =
                {
                    "custom_role",
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Also added it as a scope for a client:

```
    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        "invoices.api.scope",
        "roles.scope",
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for an **Access Token** and **Identity Token** ("code id_token") Identity Server will not include user claims by default.

The solution is to set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken` to true. See http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/client.html

The explanation on why this settings exists is here: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/14/optimizing-identity-tokens-for-size/

Comment: Thanks, but i have specifically enabled GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint and use of Reference Tokens in MVC, so the middleware would request the claims from the endpoint and not take them from the tokens. Or perhaps i missunderstand how it works?